# Print PDF duplex

Tags: java, pdf, printing, pdfbox

I use [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) to print PDF. Faced a problem that some printers do not print duplex if sent to them in PrinterJob Sides.DUPLEX. However, these printers can print duplex if they send them a prepared PCL or PS file. I found here such a link [Duplex Printing of PDF document with T&C at the Back](http://symplik.blogspot.ru/2013/10/duplex-printing-of-pdf-document-with-t.html)  The author creates a third-party ps file and adds a duplex to it. I would like to know if PDFBox can add a duplex directly to the output stream. Or maybe there is some alternative PDFBox, capable of adding duplex when printing.

```
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.File;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Sides;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;

import org.apache.pdfbox.printing.PDFPageable;

public class PrintPDFMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        try {
            File file;
            int qty;
            if (args.length < 2) {
                System.out.println("1st param File 2nd param printer name 3rd param qty of copies 4th param duplex (yes/no) \n1st and 2nd params are mandatory");
                return;
            }
            file = new File(args[0]);
            if (!file.exists()) return;
            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);

            PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

            if (args.length > 2) {

                if (args.length >= 3) {
                    qty = 1;
                    try {
                        qty = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        qty = 1;
                    }
                    System.out.println(qty);
                    pras.add(new Copies(qty));
                }
                if (args.length >= 4) {
                    if (args[3].length() == 3) {
                        System.out.println(args[3]);
                        pras.add(Sides.DUPLEX);
                    }
                }
            }

            PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document));
            job.print(pras);

            System.out.println("print");
            System.out.println();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error " + e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The PDF specification mentions it... but printing like above does not send a PDF file to a printer, it sends the rendering commands to the printer by reading the PDF. So my understanding is that a PDF application should query the setting (from "Entries in a viewer preferences dictionary") and then set the `Sides.DUPLEX` option like you mention. The link shows streaming directly from PS to a printer, PDFBox doesn't know nor care what printer language is used.

Comment: Identical issue here with CUPS-based systems.  I have a feeling it's a JDK bug.  I've opened an issue with our JDK support provider to investigate further.  
 Our downstream report is here: https://github.com/qzind/tray/issues/844

Answer (score 0):

After a thorough check, I found the printer was detected in the system as a model without duplex. After reinstalling the drivers, everything worked.